# Rationally connected spaces over non-algebraically-closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The definition I most often see for what it means for a projective variety $X$ over a field $k$ to be rationally connected is that there exists a variety $M$ and a dominant morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1\times M \to X\times X$. For instance, this is the definition given in both Kollar's "Rational curves on algebraic varieties" and Debarre's "Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry". Both books claim that, for $k$ algebraically closed, this implies the existence of a rational curve connecting any two general geometric points. However, I don't understand why the field needs to be algebraically closed
 for this to be true, it seems that a pretty straightforward argument could be made for arbitrary base field.

With this in mind, could anyone provide any examples of rationally connected varieties which don't necessarily possess rational curves between a general pair of points?

Comment: There are counterexamples over $k=\mathbb{R}$ coming from the fact that $X(\mathbb{R})$ can be disconnected, yet $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ is connected (for the analytic topology).  For instance, inside $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^2$ with homogeneous coordinates $([s,t],[u,v,w])$, consider the zero scheme of $s^3(u^2+v^2) = t(t^2-s^2)w^2$.  The image in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ of the real points are the open intervals $-1\leq t/s\leq 0$ and $0\leq s/t \leq 1$.  On the other hand, it is not difficult to construct a morphism $u:\mathbb{P}^1\times M \to X$ with $u^{(2)}$ dominant.

Comment: @JasonStarr Although you say that such a map is "not difficult to construct", I'm having trouble seeing how one could possibly exist, let how one is constructed. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more?

Comment: "Would you mind elaborating a little bit more?"  Begin with a smooth fiber of the conic bundle over a real point and that contains a real point.  Glue on a complex conjugate pair of very free sections.  Deform.  Rinse.  Repeat.

Comment: Your definition is copied wrong from both sources as Jason politely tried to point out. What is fun about the "correct" definition is that it does not a priori guarantee the existence of a single nonconstant morphism $\mathbf{P}^1_k \to X$ over $k$; for example $M$ need not have any $k$-rational point. So I do not see why you say "pretty straightforward". (Also, please be careful, if you are working over a general field $k$, then there are at least two intelligent ways to define varieties over $k$ and you need to make sure your references use the same definition...)

Comment: Maybe I should not have written "rinse, repeat".  Anyway, this construction is in Koll'ar's article about rational curves and R-equivalence over local fields (for these purposes, the field of real numbers behaves like a local field).

Comment: I have a counter-example even simpler than Jason's. Let $X$ be the real projective conic without real point ($u^2+v^2+w^2=0$ in homogeneous coordinates). Over every field $K$ over which $X$ gets a rational point, this point provides an isomorphism between $X_K$ and $\mathbb P^1_K$ (by considering the intersection of a line going through this point with $X$, this is the old-fashioned rational parametrization of a conic). 

This construction then gives rise to a dominant map $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}\times_{\mathbb R}X\to X$.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong; I think that my construction will give a dominant map $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}\times_{\mathbb R}U\to X$ for some dense Zariski-open subset $U$ of $X$, but I am not completely sure that I can extend it to the whole of $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb R}\times_{\mathbb R}X$ without blowing-up. Nevertheless, it still provides a dominant map, but its source is not proper.
(The point is that the identification between $\mathbb P^1$ and the set of lines going through a point of the projective plane is not canonical; it can be described by a uniform formula only on a given affine chart).

Comment: @AntoineDucros If $X$ is a conic, then the second projection $p_2$ gives $X\times X$ the structure of a Severi-Brauer scheme over $X$, and since it has a section (the diagonal), it is isomorphic to $\mathbf P^1\times X$.

Comment: Oh yes of course! Do you think that both maps more or less coincide ?

Comment: They should, because what you wrote is nothing but "any conic with a point is isomorphic to the projective line" in the relative setting.

Comment: Wait... Is a trivial S-B scheme over $X$ isomorphic to $\mathbb P^n_X$ or to $\mathbb P(\mathscr E)$ for some vector bundle $\mathscr E$ ? I think that the second statement is true, but not necessarily the first one.

Comment: In fact the $K_0$ group of $X$ is isomorphic to $K_0(\mathbb R)\bigoplus K_0(\mathbb H)$; and I am pretty sure that $X\times X\to X$ is the projective bundle associated to the  $2$-dimensional vector bundle having for $K_0$-class the generator of $K_0(\mathbb H)$. In particular, it is not trivial.